# how to get one random record of each classes in BatchDataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensor

I have a `BatchDataset` which I got from following code.

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
"<path of images>",
seed=123,
validation_split = 0.2,
subset =  "training",
image_size=(180, 180),
batch_size=32)
```

As per the folder structure, this Dataset has got 9 classes.

Now I will need to displace one random  image of all classes. And for this I will need to have one random record  for every classes. which I am not sure how to do.

Any help or direction will be appricated.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly then random.choice() will help you